# Nearly degenerate eigenenergies in perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, perturbation-theory, singularities

The second-order correction to the energy of an eigenstate due to a perturbation $H'$ is given by:

$$E_n^2=\sum_{m\not=n}^{} \frac{\left \lvert \left \langle \psi_m^0|H'|\psi_n^0 \right \rangle \right \rvert^2}{E_n^0-E_m^0}$$

If $E_n^0 \approx E_m^0$, the expression above blows up. In some undergraduate quantum mechanics textbooks like Griffiths' or Binney's, only the case where $E_n^0=E_m^0$ is analyzed using degenerate perturbation theory. What does one do in the case where $E_n^0 \approx E_m^0$ and not $E_n^0=E_m^0$? I am having trouble finding resources that explain how to systematically approach the case where $E_n^0 \approx E_m^0$. If you could please provide an explanation below or guide me toward the right resources, I would be grateful.

Comment: Simply follow similar steps in the degenerate case, but with the gap?

Comment: Check out a toy case, e.g. H=diag ( a+ε, a, b) and a suitable simple off-diagonal H'...

Comment: You treat the difference in energies as a perturbation. This is actually the (implicit) context of Griffiths Problem 7.12 (in the 3rd edition), and I'll think that you'll find that many quantum texts *do* treat this situation explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/2021/221.html) (see the [file](https://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/notes/pertth.pdf)) is the discussion of the case you are interested in. It is referred as "nearly degenerate perturbation theory", and it is reduced to a usual degenerate perturbation theory by a simple rearrangement of terms in Hamiltonian. The resulting secular equation differs from the degenerate perturbation theory by a simple modification:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
E_m^{(0)} + V_{mm} - \epsilon_\alpha & V_{mn}\\
V_{nm} & E_n^{(0)} + V_{nn} - \epsilon_\alpha
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_m^\alpha\\
c_n^\alpha
\end{pmatrix} = 0.
\end{equation}
where $c^{\alpha}_k$ are the coefficients of the zero-order eigenstates
$|\alpha\rangle = c^\alpha_m|\psi^{(0)}_m\rangle + c^\alpha_n|\psi_n^{(0)}\rangle$ with the first-order corrected energies $\epsilon_\alpha$.

The rearrangement is performed as follows. Consider a Hamiltonian $H = H_0 + V$, where
\begin{equation}
 H_0 = \sum_i E_i^{(0)}|\psi_i^{(0)}\rangle\langle \psi_i^{(0)}|,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 V = \sum_{ij} V_{ij}|\psi_i^{(0)}\rangle\langle \psi_j^{(0)}|,
\end{equation}
where $E_n^{(0)} \approx E_m^{(0)}$ for some $m$,$n$. Now, let me write \begin{equation}
H = H_0' + V',
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
H_0' = H_0 - \frac{E_m^{(0)} - E_n^{(0)}}{2}(|\psi_m^{(0)}\rangle\langle \psi_m^{(0)}| - |\psi_n^{(0)}\rangle\langle \psi_n^{(0)}|), 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
V' = V + \frac{E_m^{(0)} - E_n^{(0)}}{2}(|\psi_m^{(0)}\rangle\langle \psi_m^{(0)}| - |\psi_n^{(0)}\rangle\langle \psi_n^{(0)}|).
\end{equation}
The Hamiltonian $H'$ has two strictly degenerate eigenstates $|\psi_m^{(0)}\rangle$ and $|\psi_n^{(0)}\rangle$ with the energies $(E_m^{(0)} + E_n^{(0)})/2$, which allows to use usual degenerate perturbation theory by $V'$.